# RegEx For 4 digit unique string

Tags: regex, numbers, unique, digit

I need RegEx which will check my string is a number and is of 4 digits. Also not starting with 0 and no number is repeated.

e.g:

- 1234 is correct
- 0123 is not correct
- 234 is not correct
- 2334 is not correct
- 7890 is correct

Comment: Have you tried anything? besides just asking us?

Answer (score 0):

This sort of problem is so hard using a regex, and so *easy with absolutely anything else*.

Be that as it may though, you can use a bunch of lookaheads and capturing groups to make this work, something along the lines of:

```
([1-9])(?!.*\1)([0-9])(?!.*\2)([0-9])(?!.*\3)([0-9])(?!.*\4)
```

If you just care about the four digits, and aren't concerned about anything found on the rest of the line/input, apart from those four digits, you can reign in the length of the lookaheads, like:

```
([1-9])(?!.{0,2}\1)([0-9])(?!.{0,1}\2)([0-9])(?!\3)([0-9])
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked like a charm.

I know it's better to solve these kind of problem by taking other approaches but am learning RegEx and was not able to do this, so requested you guys.